# Names of two cosmetics

Tags: vocabulary

There are two cosmetics used in South Asia called Kajal and Surma.

This is Surma:

[image]

It is a dry powder.

The image below is of Kajal:

[image]

It is not dry, it's got some substance that makes is greasy.

What are the English words for these two?

***Which one is antimony? And which one is kohl?***

Comment: Kohl is the one you put around your eyes. I have no idea what antimony is as a cosmetic.

Comment: Why do you think either of these might be called "antimony" or "kohl?" I'm no expert on cosmetics, but as far as I know [antimony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimony) is just a chemical element with atomic number 51.

Answer (score 1):

My daughter-in-law works for a cosmetics company in marketing. I am not sure that anyone there speaks any natural language when it comes to naming cosmetics. The whole business is based on the supposition that what color lipstick you choose will make you sexually irresistible despite your acne, obesity, age, personality, or any combination of the preceding.

However, “powder” is a perfectly good word, generally understood with few if any negative connotation, but it implies apparent absence of any moisture.

When it comes to things that are moist, there are many words that distinguish between degrees of moisture without being negative: “paste,” “gel,” “cream,” and “wash” are all possibilities.

Comment: ***Which one is antimony? And which one is kohl?*** Added to my question

Comment: "the supposition that what color lipstick you choose will make you sexually irresistible despite your acne, obesity, age, [or] personality" - it has always worked for me.